# Changing CSS style from ASP.NET code

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change CSS Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501577/change-css-dynamically)

I need to change the height of a div container(CSS Property Height) from ASP.NET code (VB).

How can I do that?

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501577/change-css-dynamically

Answer (score 37, accepted):

C#, because I don't want to typo the VB syntax.

Markup:

> ```
> <div runat="server" id="divControl">...</div>
> ```

Class of the Page:

> ```
> protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divControl;
> ```

OnLoad/Other function:

> ```
> divControl.Style.Add("height", number / anotherNumer);
> ```

Comment: control you mean the ID of the div?

Comment: Thanks anyway, but i dont knwo c#  syntax....

Comment: @David, even if you don't write in C#, it would probably be helpful to at least learn how to read and translate it.  I think you'll find that many examples for new stuff from Microsoft will come out first in C#.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Agreed, it's an excellent skill to have

Comment: @AviewAnew - In your example changing the code under the class section to "Dim divControl as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl" will fit VB.NET

Comment: just to clarify the answer: if you have an existing div, add the runat=server and the id=, this will *automatically generate* the 'class of page' row shown above in the class.aspx.designer.cs file with a field by the name of the id you used. now you just need to use it in your class.apsx.cs file

Comment: there is a typo above, instead of divControl.Styles.Add should be divControl.Style.Add

Comment: this also works for VB ;), you only need the top and bottom code samples though, no need for `protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl divControl;`

Answer (score 7):

VB Version:

Class:

```
Protected divControl As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl
```

OnLoad/Other function:

```
divControl.Style("height") = "200px"
```

I've never tried the Add method with the styles.  What if the height already exists on the DIV?

Answer (score 2):

As a NOT TO DO - Another way would be to use:

```
divControl.Attributes.Add("style", "height: number");
```

But don't use this as its messy and the answer by AviewAnew is the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

If your div is an ASP.NET control with runat="server" then AviewAnew's answer should do it. If it's just an HTML div, then you'd probably want to use JavaScript.  Can you add the actual div tag to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I find that code gets messy fast when C# code is used to modify CSS values. Perhaps a better approach is for your code to dynamically set the class attribute on the div tag and then store any specific CSS settings in the style sheet.

That might not work for your situation, but its a decent default position if you need to change the style on the fly in server side code.