# Change CSS Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I need to determine which **CSS** should be applied on some specific pages. I have a master page which has children and **default.aspx** and **services.aspx** are ones of the children of Master page. What I want to is when user navigates **Default.aspx** or **Services.aspx**,system should apply **DefaultCSS** file otherwise I want to apply some **ordinary css** file.

How can I do that and for this question what kind of practice would be better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I've found what I am looking for :

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
        css.Href = "css/fancyforms.css";
        css.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
        css.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
        css.Attributes["media"] = "all";
        Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
    }
```

Also MSDN was describing how to achieve this : [HtmlLink Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmllink(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Its much easier and more flexible to do this:

**MasterPage:**

```
<head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

**Child-Page 1:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="css/fancyforms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

**Child-Page 2:**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link href="css/NOTfancyforms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Yeap, you are right but I don't know I just wanted to get fancy about that but I liked your solution more than mine.

Comment: The benefit of this approach is that if you change your .css, .js, meta tags...whatever, you don't have to re-compile anything. You will also get design-time support in Visual Studio for your .aspx.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to investigate using themes as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykzx33wh.aspx

Comment: Thanks, actually it was also nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the CSS file declaratively, i.e. in the `*.aspx` file: see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568717/asp-net-masterpages-how-to-insert-markup-in-the-head-section-inside-the-aspx/568908#568908).