# aspx ASP.NET setting CssClass

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

In the webforms application, I am trying to conditionally set the CssClass for this panel like this, but it does not work...

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlFooter" runat="server"  Width="26.67cm" CssClass="">
<% If (prpLastVID() = Eval("UID_VEHICLE")) Then 
    CType(lstView.FindControl("pnlFooter"), Panel).Attributes("CssClass")="RPT_footer"%>
```

I need to apply the cssClass "RPT_footer" only when the last vehicle record/row is being placed into the lstView so that the footer appears at the bottom of the page.

```
CSS: (.RPT_footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; width:100%; } ).
```

Any suggestions will be very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to set cssclass on client side use for example java script or [jquery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_addclass.asp) function. In this solution you must set OnClientClick attribute on webcontrols with behaviour which actually changing panel style.
If you prefer set on server side look for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403031/changing-css-style-from-asp-net-code).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CType(lstView.FindControl("pnlFooter"), Panel).CssClass="RPT_footer"
```

or:

```
CType(lstView.FindControl("pnlFooter"), Panel).Attributes.Add("class","RPT_footer")
```